# How to run CMD commands on windows startup?

Tags: windows, cmd

I am curious to see if you can open cool stuff like websites or run certain things that cant be put into the startup folder normally. I was originally thinking to make an executable file with the code in it and run that on start but I'm not sure how to do that either. Is there any way to do what I am trying to accomplish? And if so please answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the cmd in a text file, save it as a .bat file and add a shortcut to the file in the startup folder. Typing `shell:startup` will open the startup folder. Save a shortcut there and it should execute.